# rating value is not appearing

Tags: c#, asp.net

> how to get rating ajax id from a data list in code behind
> asp.net.The value of the rating should come from database and display

.

***web form***

```
 <asp:datalist id="viewjobdetails" clientidmode="Static" runat="server" datakeynames="Job_ID">
    <itemtemplate>
    <ajaxtoolkit:rating id="Ratinghk" runat="server" behaviorid="RatingBehavior1"
    ="" currentrating="0" maxrating="5" starcssclass="ratingStar" waitingstarcssclass="savedRatingStar" filledstarcssclass="filledRatingStar" emptystarcssclass="emptyRatingStar" style="float: left;">
    <asp:label id="lblRatingStatus" runat="server">
 </<ajaxtoolkit></itemtemplate>
 </asp:datalist>
```

**Code Behind**

```
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
    DataTable dt = this.GetData("SELECT ISNULL(AVG(Reviews), 0) AverageRating, COUNT(Reviews) RatingCount FROM tblHKHOReviews where HK_ID=" + Request.QueryString["ID"]);
    Ratinghk.CurrentRating = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["AverageRating"]);
    lblRatingStatus.Text = string.Format("{0} Users have rated. Average Rating {1}", dt.Rows[0]["RatingCount"], dt.Rows[0]["AverageRating"]);
    }

    private DataTable GetData(string query)
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
             
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_conString))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
                    {
                        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                        {
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                            cmd.Connection = con;
                            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                            sda.Fill(dt);
                        }
                    }
                    return dt;
                }
            }
```

Comment: That c# code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks, you should consider using parametrized queries instead.

Comment: Besides the SQLi already mentioned, it is unclear to me what your problem is. Is your code not being executed? It executes but does not work as intended? Consider editing your question and being more clear